# Php Memcached Failover : Server is Marked Dead

Tags: php, memcached, pecl

I am trying to use PECL/Memcached Extension for Php. I have enabled consistent hashing. So I have two memcached servers running. First I assign 1000 key value pairs using set. This makes sure I have enough keys on both the servers. Now I try to get values from the cache. Everything works fine till I take down one server. In my script I try to get the value and if it is not found I set it. But all I see is **Server is Marked Dead**

Has anyone got consistent hashing working with PECL/Memcached?